Event handlers are removed in chrome when moving an element out of window then back to it
I have an element that I move from the current window to an external window as follows:
element.after(anchor);
externalWindow.document.body.append(element);

In the external window, the element and all its descendants will have their event handlers working properly. However, when I move the element back to the main window:
anchor.after(externalWindow.document.body.firstChild);

The element behaves on 2 different ways depending on the browser.

Firefox: event handlers are working properly.
Chrome: no event handlers are found on the element nor any of its descendants.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?
